# VBA unexpected result in bitwise AND of long data if bit 15 is set and MSB

Tags: vba, bitwise-and

Here's an example executed in the VBA immediate window of a bitwise AND of two long (32bit) values if bit 15 is set in an operand and it is the MSB. The upper 16 bits are not properly ANDed.

```
? Hex(&H44332211 And &H00008000)
44330000
```

Same problem when performing the operation in VBA code.
Observed in Excel 2003 SP3 32-bit, in Office 2016 & 365 64-bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that `&H00008000` gets interpreted as `&H8000` and evaluated as `-32768` Integer

Comment: Yes, exactly. Still somehow unexpected as
? Hex(&H44332211 And 65535)
works. While 
? Hex(&H44332211 And &HFFFF)
does not.

Comment: Surprise. I forgot the closing &.
&HFFFF& works.